ParallelStrams with hibernate entity with lazy load with exception JdbcValuesSourceProcessingState
I have the entity PROJECT with the Child OUTPUS (relational @OneToMany).
In my app, i need get more tha 50000 projects by database and after get the OUTPUT information.
After get the 50000 projects, for performance, i try user the parallelStream, but when run the code, the exception is throwed: Illegal pop() with non-matching JdbcValuesSourceProcessingState
In my search, the JdbcValuesSourceProcessingState is relationed with transactionals in the hibernate.
Entity:
Can you help me?
public class Project {
@Id
private Long id;

private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "project")
private List<Output> outputs;

}
My code for get output information:
List<Project> projects = projectRepository.findAll();
    Set<SearchOutput> searchOutputs = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>());
    projects.parallelStream().forEach(project -> {
        try {
            project.getOutputs().forEach(output->{
                SearchOutput searchOutput = new SearchOutput(project.getId(),output.getPath(),output.getName(),false);
                    searchOutputs.add(searchOutput);
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("ProjectID: {} - {}", project.getId(), e.getMessage());
            //throw new RuntimeException(e);

        }
    });


DOn't, this is highly inefficient. Instead write a proper query which returns directly what you want and create the SearchOutput directly. For this you can leverage a JPQL query. Which is a lot easier and probably even faster.

Can you show the full stack trace?

Don't do things like this, especially when using JPA. You don't want to basically pull everything from the database, throw away 80% and use just 3 fields. This is inefficient for multiple reasons.
Instead either use projections which return the results you want as it or write a query which exactly returns what you want. JPQL is very powerful with that.
@Query("SELECT new SearchOutput(p.id, o.path, o.name, false) FROM Project p JOIN p.outputs o");
@QueryHints(@jakarta.persistence.QueryHint(name="org.hibernate.fetchSize", value="1000"))
Set<SearchOutput> findAllSearchOutput();

Now if there are many results you want to improve the jdbc fetch size to reduce the network roundtrips. (Hence the @QueryHints).
With this there is no need to retrieve everything, but it will retrieve exactly what you want.
